# How can I define return value as truthy in Flowtype?

Tags: javascript, boolean, flowtype

With a function like this the return value will always be truthy, not necessary `true`, and not necessary `any`. Is there any way to define that the return value for this function will be `truthy`?

```
function cleanTruthy (value: any) {
  if (!value) return true
  return value
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, in which scenario would you use a function like this? My narrow mind can't think of any.

Comment: @ahstro I'm not going to be able to provide a case, even if I did it's usage is subjective. I'm exploring types and I'd love to be able to have a case for this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is possible by overloading a method in a separate module declaration. The following works (I'm not sure if it's possible without module declarations):

```
/* @flow */

declare function cleanTruthy(V: false | 0 | null | typeof undefined | ""): true;
declare function cleanTruthy<V: any>(v: V): V;


const truthy: 1 = cleanTruthy(1);
const falsy: true = cleanTruthy(false);
```

[Here is a working version](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVATApgYxgQwCcswoBXAOxwBcBLOCsPLfCgFULOoAsBPACgBqALlL4YAZxIAfMAAYwsimRgxFYarwAOWOFDCVsUWhSwZ1AIgsBKUdU5YA3JlwFipSjXqNmrDlz4AHhEwVl4APn4AN1FBWzBBZ3QcBglqDU4eXlEARjAAXiYYFnZMvn4c62cUijSxSWyMshJC31KAgShxKSqgA).

However, type polymorphism is not usually the best way to go, and flow will have to recompile every time you change a module file.

A better approach might be to create a function like this, that returns a solid boolean based on the logic of truthiness:

```
function isTruthy(v: any): boolean {
  return !!v;
}

if(isTruthy(v)) {
  // do something
}
```